# Cumulative count of occurence on date PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum, find-occurrences

dataset resembles this:

```
ID          Milestone
id1         01/01/2020
id2         02/01/2020
id3         04/01/2020
id4         null
id5         02/01/2020
id6         12/01/2020
```

I'm trying to count the number of records have reached the milestone before a certain date, in other words to count a cumulative total of occurences. I currently have this DAX measure:

```
#Measure = 
calculate(
    COUNTROWS(table), 
    filter(
        table, 
        table[milestone].[Date] <= MAX(table[milestone].[Date])
    )
)+0
```

But this doesn't seem to give me the desired result:

[Picture of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXo2I.png)

As you can see, it doesn't add the count of previous occurences to the current date count.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

An example after using the feedback provided by msta42a :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This work for me:

```
Measure = calculate(COUNTROWS('Table')
,FILTER(ALL('Table'[Mileston]), not(ISBLANK('Table'[Mileston])) && 'Table'[Mileston]<= 
SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Mileston])))
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed this works, seems the selectedvalue did what I was looking for.

Comment: Hmm still not quite convinced, if I look in detail I can still see some milestone dates show a decrease. When cumulating this should be impossible.

Comment: Sure, I have added a screenshot in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where is the issue. [milestone] is date type or String formated as date.

try with DATEVALUE(table[milestone])

Comment: All milestones are of type date. Regardless, I tried your suggestion to add datevalue() but it has no influence on the results.

Comment: Its really odd. Are you add something more to table/visual?  
In a "Data" tab, create a NewTable, but put here only a few day. around this one with error. 20/11/2016; Put measure in it. As additional step add simply countrows for a Date. Don't format your column.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Measure** is very close to your requirement. Here below is the adjusted code-

```
#Measure = 
calculate(
    COUNTROWS(table), 
    filter(
        ALL(table), 
        table[milestone] <= MAX(table[milestone])
    )
)+0
```

Comment: Sorry but this results in a total count of all rows

Comment: Ar you creating a custom column? This code is for measure.

Comment: No, i'm using measure.

Comment: That case this should work as I have tested here. Is your given sample data synced with your original data?

Comment: Yes, ID column is a unique identifier column and milestones are dates where a null value is also possible if the milestone hasn't been reached yet.

Comment: You should add your expected output for the given sample data.

Comment: Expected output is a calculation per date of how many previous occurences/dates there were found.